# gevent, requests and unhandled exception

Tags: python, gevent

I have code:

```
import gevent
import gevent.monkey; gevent.monkey.patch_all()
import requests

def func():
    try:
        requests.get('http://unavailable-host/')
    except:
        pass

def main():
    jobs = [gevent.spawn(func) for i in xrange(10)]
    gevent.joinall(jobs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This script usually nothing output. But sometimes (in 1 of 5 runs) i get this message:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

Explain me, why this happen, and what is right solution? Also, if I add

```
gevent.sleep(1)
```

after

```
gevent.joinall(jobs)
```

script always nothing output, all is ok.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

This seems like it has to do with a thread trying to do stuff (like print to stdout/stderr) after the main program has already exited.

See [Python Bugs: issue1722344](http://bugs.python.org/issue1722344) for reference,

and Martijn Pieters's comment in this answer to [a similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6571414/841337):

> Indeed, the error is generated because python is exiting and there is still a thread active.

**Previous (and completely incorrect) answer:**

What you are experiencing is one of the not-so-fun side effects of `monkey_patch`.

`requests` uses `socket` as the underlying mechanism for transferring data across the internet to some address. `gevent.monkey.patch_all()` replaces the stdlib `socket` with `gevent.socket`, which is an asynchronous (non-blocking) socket, and so when somewhere deep within the code (my guess goes to `http.client` which is used by `urllib`, which is in turn used by `requests`), where a `sock.recv(X)` command is made, where the code is *expected to block until X bytes are received or the socket is closed*, and instead, because the socket has been replaced by `gevent.socket`, which *returns immediately with only as many bytes as are currently in the stream buffer*, the code breaks.

The easy solution in your case, however, is to simply use [grequests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/grequests), which is requests built to use gevent (and which, in fact, does its own monkey_patch.)

Comment: When I use grequests I receive _ConnectionError_ in console. Grequest is not very good variant for me, because I want to write code in synchronous style and send chains of different requests. Is there any other variants to solve the _unhandled exception_ problem instead gevent.sleep(1)?

Comment: @Chrome Hmmm. I see. At a second inspection, it looks like nothing to do with the gevent/stdlib-socket issue. See edit for new answer.